# Oracle APEX Interactive Report conditional column link display

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an interactive report displaying all the records from articles table. For a logged in author, I would like to display all the records, but the EDIT should be displayed only for those articles written by that author. In articles table, I have the column `CREATED_BY` which has the author username.

I added a condition to Link Column as Value of Item / Column in Expression 1 = Expression 2 as Expression1=`#CREATED_BY#` & Expression2= `:APP_USER`

But this does not work. This is the first time I am taking this approach to display edit link based on a condition.

When I added the condition `Value of Item / Column in Expression 1 is not null` and set Expression1 = `#CREATED_BY#`, it was still not displaying edit link. So, I think that `#CREATED_BY#` is returning null. But the record in table has a value & I also see it in report column.

Can someone help? I don't know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 8):

The condition you use is for the column and not for each row so you will not be able to do it that way.

I think that the best way to achieve this is create a dummy column in your query that you will use as your edit link:

```
SELECT
     CASE
      WHEN CREATED_BY = :APP_USER THEN
        '<a href="' || APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL( p_url => 'f?p=' || &APP_ID. || ':<YOUR EDIT PAGE>:'||&SESSION.||'::NO::<PAGE ITEM>:'||COLUMN ID, p_checksum_type => 'SESSION') || '"><img src="/i/menu/pencil2_16x16.gif"></a>'
      ELSE ''
    END edit_link,

 ...THE REST OF YOUR QUERY...
```

You also have to change the display of the column under column definition to

> Standard Report Column

and optionally you can remove the options under

> Allow Users To:
>   so the user couldn't hide/sort/... the column.

[image: Column Definition]

Hope this can help you. Any doubt or further explanation just ask.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to come up with the solution in APEX 5, but the same should apply to APEX 4.2. You can easily do this with the **built-in APEX column link** and a **case statement** as hmarques was suggesting.

Structure your query as follows:

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN CREATED_BY = :APP_USER THEN
               'Edit'
           ELSE
               NULL
       END EDIT,
       ...rest of query
```

Then, go to: **Report Attributes** > Your **Edit** Column > and **scroll to the Column Link** portion of the page. Select the arrow next to the **Link Text** text box, and select **#EDIT#** as the column link text.

Also, set the **Link Attributes** with this html code:

```
class="t-Button t-Button--simple t-Button--hot t-Button--stretch"
```

This will make the column look like a button, and will not display the traditional pencil icon (**which is the only drawback to this method**).

[Click here to see screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrd6s.png)

Don't forget to make the edit column a **Standard Report Column** and good luck!

John

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar solution to hmarques, but it doesn't require building the whole link manually.

I would include a dummy column in the report query which contains either null, or if the current username matches CREATED_BY, a pointer to the "Edit" button image:

```
select decode(CREATED_BY
            ,:APP_USER
            ,'<img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#edit.gif" alt="">' 
                -- or your preferred image/hyperlink text
            ) EDITLINK
       --, your columns
from ARTICLES
--etc
```

Use the standard column link functionality to pass parameters to your edit page, but use `#EDITLINK#` as your column's Link Text. Don't forget to set the column's Display Type to "Standard Report Column". Personally I would also get rid of the column heading - it's a mandatory field, but you can set it to a single space.